# Select values of checkbox group with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Zend_Form to output a set group of checkboxes:

```
<label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="user_group[]" id="user_group-20" value="20">This Group</label>
```

With a normal HTTP Post these values are passed as an array, but when I'm somewhat stumped on how to grab all the values using jQuery. I figured I can select the group using:

```
$("input[@name='user_group[]']").val()
```

but that just grabs the value of the first checkbox in the list regardless of if it is checked of not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You could use the checked selector to grab only the selected ones (negating the need to know the count or to iterate over them all yourself):

```
$("input[name='user_group[]']:checked")
```

With those checked items, you can either create a collection of those values or do something to the collection:

```
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='user_group[]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
  // or you can do something to the actual checked checkboxes by working directly with  'this'
  // something like $(this).hide() (only something useful, probably) :P
});
```

Comment: `@` is not required in `$.each($("input[@name='user_group[]']:checked"), function() {`

Comment: @Ismail, it has been updated for post-1.3 jQuery. Version 1.3 was released after the answer was posted (posted Jan 06, 2009, 1.3 released Jan 14, 2009). Attribute selectors shouldn't be used by anyone using v1.3 or newer.

Comment: Can't `[name='user_group[]']` be called as attribute selector. I still use it in 1.4.2. Is there are better alternative now?

Comment: That was a typo on my part. Attribute selectors [with "@"] shouldn't be used by anyone using v1.3 or newer.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure about the "@" used in the selector.  At least with the latest jQuery, I had to remove the @ to get this to function with two different checkbox arrays, otherwise all checked items were selected for each array:

```
var items = [];
$("input[name='items[]']:checked").each(function(){items.push($(this).val());});

var about = [];
$("input[name='about[]']:checked").each(function(){about.push($(this).val());});
```

Now both, items and about work.

Comment: I believe the @ was removed in jQuery 1.3 +1

Comment: This also works if you need to get the value of all checkboxes even if they're not selected. For example I needed to create an array (hash) with all checkboxes values (selected or not) just remove the `:checked` part

Answer (score 12):

Use `.map()` (adapted from the example at http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var values = $("input[name='user_group[]']:checked").map(function(index,domElement) {
    return $(domElement).val();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

With `map` in instead of `each` it is possible to avoid the array creation step:

```
var checkedCheckboxesValues = 
    $('input:checkbox[name="groupName"]:checked')
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
```

From the `map()` page of the docs:

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values

`get()` turns those values into an array.

Comment: would give you +100 if possible ;)

Answer (score 4):

mhata dzenyu mese. its actually

```
var selectedGroups  = new Array();
$(".user_group[checked]").each(function() {
    selectedGroups.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just shortened the answer I selected a bit:

```
var selectedGroups  = new Array();
$("input[@name='user_group[]']:checked").each(function() {
    selectedGroups.push($(this).val());
});
```

and it works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% entirely sure how you want to "grab" the values.  But if you want to iterate over the checkboxes you can use .each like so:

```
("input[@name='user_group[]']").each( function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Of course a better selector is available:

```
$(':checkbox')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = $("input[name='user_group']:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

This will give you all the values of the checked boxed in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a javascript variable which stores the number of checkboxes that are emitted, i.e in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var num_cboxes=<?php echo $number_of_checkboxes;?>;
</script>
```

So if there are 10 checkboxes, starting from `user_group-1` to `user_group-10`, in the javascript code you would get their value in this way:

```
var values=new Array();
for (x=1; x<=num_cboxes; x++)
{
   values[x]=$("#user_group-" + x).val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnskillgroup').click(function(){
              getCheckedGroups('skills');
            });
   $('#btncitiesgroup').click(function(){
              getCheckedGroups('cities');
            });
         var getCheckedGroups = function(groupname){
               var result = $('input[name="'+groupname+'"]:checked');
              if (result.length > 0) {
               var resultstring = result.length +"checkboxes checked <br>";
               result.each(function(){
                resultstring += $(this).val()+" <br>"; //append value to exsiting var
               });
       $('#div'+groupname).html(resultstring);
      }else{
       $('#div'+groupname).html(" No checkbox  is Checked");
      }
         
         };
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Skills:<input type="checkbox" name="skill"  value="Java"> Java
    <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="Jquery"> Jquery
    <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="PHP"> PHP
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cities"  value="Pune"> Pune
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities" value="Baramati"> Baramati
    <input type="checkbox" name="cities" value="London"> London

    <input type="submit" id="btnskillgroup" value="Get Checked Skill group">
<input type="submit" id="btncitiesgroup" value="Get cities checked group">
    <div id="divskills"></div>
<div id="divcities"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you have implemented very precisely .