# jQuery MultiSelect , how to get information about selected options

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have a problem , i know only the basics of jQuery , and i need to get the information with JavaScript about selected options from the list  , i wasted 2 days searching for a good method , but without success , please help ...
script of MultiSelect is here [link text](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/) , I need only to get the title of selected option and numbers of selected elements , or to give idea how to do... Sorry for my English

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an API to do that; I'd ask the plugin's author. The best I can come up with is `$("form").serializeArray()` and work with that.

I get more and more convinced that jQuery leans too much to the "dynamic" side..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns your select box into a bunch of checkboxes. so you'd get the info the same way you'd get it from checkboxes.

[Select values of checkbox group with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416752/select-values-of-checkbox-group-with-jquery/416870#416870)

if your multiple select box had `id='option8'` then your checkboxes would have `name='option8[]'`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I solved the problem , i didn't think about this method  , i was concentrated how to get from data from api of script , and  i spent a lot of time searching for information to solve the problem , after your answer , i spent only 20 min ... Thanks !