# jQuery Array of all selected checkboxes (by class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select values of checkbox group with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416752/select-values-of-checkbox-group-with-jquery)

In HTML I have a set of checkboxes grouped together by a class. I want to get an array in jQuery containing all the checkboxes that are selected/checked for that class (so other checkboxes on the page are ignored).

So HTML code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="18" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="20" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group2" value="14" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="55" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="10" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group2" value="77" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="11" />
```

Would return the values of the checked/selected `group1` checkboxes into an array like this:

```
var values = [ 18, 55, 10 ];
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can use the [`:checkbox`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox) and [`:checked`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) pseudo-selectors and the `.class` selector, with that you will make sure that you are getting the right elements, only checked checkboxes with the class you specify.

Then you can easily use the [Traversing/map](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) method to get an array of values:

```
var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.group1').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get(); // ["18", "55", "10"]
```

Comment: How would you do this using the elements name instead of a class?

Comment: Used this for reference, thanks. And to answer the last comment, use selector: $('input:checkbox[name=SOMENAME]')

Comment: @user387049 you may use it so (assume sector4 being the name of checkbox array):
 `$("input[name='sector4[]']:checkbox:checked").each(function() { });`

Comment: I didn't need to use `.get()` at all and worked fine. To be honest, use it throwed an error. It should be a jquery version related issue.

Comment: How can I make it so that it gives me that in the `change` function? Thanks

Answer (score 32):

```
var matches = [];
$(".className:checked").each(function() {
    matches.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: ...will give you a jQuery object, and not an array.

Comment: thanks Stefan, didn't realize an array of values was needed :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also add [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to your project and will be able to do it in one line:

```
_.map($("input[name='category_ids[]']:checked"), function(el){return $(el).val()})
```

Comment: “one line”; that’s one *very long* line…