# jQuery checkbox values to comma separated list

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, checkbox, delimiter

I have several checkboxes with a name array and I want the output of the checked boxes to be a variable with a comma separated list.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="288" />
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="289" />
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="290" />
```

For example if the first and last box are selected the output will be:

```
var output = "288,290";
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Array of all selected checkboxes (by class)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099164/jquery-array-of-all-selected-checkboxes-by-class)

Answer (score 36):

You can use `:checkbox` and name attribute selector (`:checkbox[name=example\\[\\]]`) to get the list of checkbox with `name="example[]"` and then you can use `:checked` filter to get only the selected checkbox.

Then you can use `.map` function to create an array out of the selected checkbox.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6LCvN/22/)

```
var output = $.map($(':checkbox[name=example\\[\\]]:checked'), function(n, i){
      return n.value;
}).join(',');
```

Comment: Hmmm, this seems to return a list of all (checked) checkboxes even with those without the name of example[].  e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/6LCvN/ .  Any idea why?

Comment: @Hugh Missed it somehow, but you need double slashes to escape the `[` and `]` http://jsfiddle.net/6LCvN/22/ or wrap in quotes http://jsfiddle.net/hmtdtwbr/

Answer (score 12):

Currently un-tested, but I believe the following should work:

```
var valuesArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join();
```

Edited, after a small break, to use native DOM, rather than `$(this).val()` (which is needlessly expensive, in context):

```
var valuesArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map( function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> var valuesArray = $('input[name="valuehere"]:checked').map(function () {  
>         return this.value;
>         }).get().join(",");
> ```

works for me always

Comment: I had to add this square brackets.

Comment: var valuesArray = $('input[name="valuehere[]"]:checked').map(function () {  
        return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");