# PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checkboxes in single click and also get values in single click for each values

Tags: javascript, php

> I have a question regarding a php form. I've added a checkbox I would
>   like it to select all in one click and click it separately.

```
<form name=myform action="addcanteen.php" method=post>
    <table><tr><td width="11%"> Date:</td><td width="89%"><input type="date" name="cdate" id="cdate"/></td></tr></table>
    <table border="1" bgcolor="#F5F9C1">
    <tr>
    <!--<th>ID</th>-->
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><!--<input type="text" id="datepicker">-->
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" name="chk[]"/></td>
    <td align="center">coffee</td>  
    <td align="center">tea</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <?php /*?><td><?php echo $row['emp_id'];?></td><?php */?>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_name'];?></td>

    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="name" name="chk1[]" value="<?php echo $row['emp_name'];?>"/></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="coffee[]" id="coffee" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tea[]" id="tea" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

> here is the php code for the insertion, everything  works there
>   except the insertion of single checkbox selection.

```
<?php
    include(dbcon.php);
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    /*$d=date("D");*/
    $date=date("d");
    $month=date("m");
    $year=date("Y");
    $fd=date("d-m-Y");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $cdate=$_POST['cdate'];
    //$emp_id=$_POST['emp_id'];
    $checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];
    $tea=$_POST['tea'];
    $coffee=$_POST['coffee'];
    /*$dd=date("d-m-y");*/
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++) 
    {
    $query1="INSERT INTO canteen(name,coffee,tea,date)VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$coffee[$i]."','".$tea[$i]."','$cdate')";
    $sql1=mysql_query($query1);
    }
    }
    header("location:canteen.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: where is your html code and what error you got using your code?

Comment: @saty i commented my problem below...please help me

Comment: you want when you check selectall checkbox all the checkbox inside you while loop is also selected??

Comment: @saty thanks for your time...yes. i need that function..when i click select all check box data enters properly..but when i click one separately only text name was inserted..i need to insert the number of coffee and tea with this name.I would be really grateful for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I do get your point, But I suggest you to use map function in JavaScript with reference to class. [For more info refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099164/jquery-array-of-all-selected-checkboxes-by-class)

Comment: Imagine you have a check box labelled as Select All and on click of that trigger all check boxes to get selected through a function and the write the code for map function as described in the link above, so that the check boxes which are checked, their values will be returned.