# Pass an array as parameter to a controller from an ajax call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and I've got some troubles with a functionality. I explain, I've to select entities displayed in a table with their linked checkbox :

[Screenshot of my table where each row has a checkbox with the same Id as the entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyzMD.png)

[Console showing updates in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6h5K.png)

Inside my script I have been abled to store each checked Id's checkbox in an array and remove those if the checkbox is unchecked. But I can't pass the array to my controller's function to delete each selected entity in the database.
I used `$.ajax()` from jquery to send through a POST request the array (as JSON) but I always get 500 error :

- JSON primitive invalid
- Null reference

Here's my function in my script (I don't know if my array's format is valid) :

```
    var sendDocsToDelete = function (docsArray) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Main/DeleteDocuments',
            data: JSON.stringify(docsArray),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Success ' + result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Fail ' + result.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Then, the POST call the following function in my controller :

```
    [Authorize]
    [WebMethod]
    public void DeleteDocuments(string docsToDelete)
    {
        int id; 
        string[] arrayDocs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(docsToDelete);

        foreach (string docId in arrayDocs)
        {
            int.TryParse(docId, out id);
            dal.DeleteDocument(id); // dal = DataAccessLayer is the class which interacts with the database by executing queries (select, delete, update...)
        }
    }
```

### Update 2

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DeleteDocuments(int[] docsToDelete)
    {
        try{
               foreach (string docId in arrayDocs)
               {
                       int.TryParse(docId, out id);
                       dal.DeleteDocument(id); // dal = DataAccessLayer is the class which interacts with the database by executing queries (select, delete, update...)
               }
               return Json("Success");
        } 
        catch 
        {
               return Json("Error");
        }
    }


    var sendDocsToDelete = function (docsArray) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Main/DeleteDocuments',
            data: docsArray,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Success ' + result.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Fail ' + result.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas about this issue ? I hoped I was clear enough. Do not hesitate if you need more details.

Comment: why using a webMethod in MVC ? you can just use ActionResult

Comment: You don't need to `stringify` the data yourself, just pass the array as it is. And you don't need to deserialize it yourself either, just accept `string[] docsToDelete` and let the modelbinder handle that for you.

Comment: @Reddy I thought it was compulsory by this way because I wasn't expecting a view but an asynchronous update of the actual view.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I tried but it still fails to recognize my parameter...

Comment: @Loïc you can pass back string too from the ActionResult..

Comment: If you are passing `docsArray` from ajax then same variable name should be used in server side method like `DeleteDocuments(int[] docsArray)`..... And If you are returning `"Success"` as string then you will get same on ajax `success: function (result) {` ... here value of `result` will be `"Success"`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are passing an integer array properly from `$.ajax` (i.e. your `docsArray` should be having value like `[15,18,25,30,42,49]`) then you should try :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DeleteDocuments(int[] docsArray)
{
    //int id; 
    //string[] arrayDocs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(docsToDelete);
  try {
    foreach (int docId in docsArray)
    {
        //int.TryParse(docId, out id);
        dal.DeleteDocument(docId); // dal = DataAccessLayer is the class which interacts with the database by executing queries (select, delete, update...)
    }
    return "Success ";
  }
  catch {
        return "Error";
  }
}
```

### Update :

Your javascript code should be :

```
var sendDocsToDelete = function (docsArray) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Main/DeleteDocuments',
        data: JSON.stringify(docsArray),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Success ');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Fail ');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It have to parse it because my Ids are "checkbox123"

Comment: "checkbox123" can not be parse in `int`, you have to pass integer ids like 123 only.. you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099164/jquery-array-of-all-selected-checkboxes-by-class

Comment: I doubt that AJAX will even hit this method in the first place. Its not a ActionResult

Comment: Thanks @Reddy, added ActionResult

Comment: @Sachin @Reddy So, I change Ids to be integer (in my view and when I push values in array). But I get again the exception : `System.ArgumentException - Primitive JSON invalid : undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the datatype in the JSON array is not a string? (This could happen if you have an array in the form of `[45,64,34,6]`, or a mixed one like `[345,"wef4"]`).

To make sure something is a string in Javascript you can do this: `var string = "".concat(otherVar);`

Comment: Each element in my array are Id defined in my view such as "checkbox123" and in the console I print each value.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ajax data to something like this..

```
 data : JSON.stringify({'docsToDelete':docsArray}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your code.

---

***In Jquery***

`data: docsArray,`  no need to stringify the array

---

***In Controller***

```
    [Authorize]                                                //remove [WebMethod]
    public ActionResult DeleteDocuments(string[] docsToDelete) //Add ActionResult, Change parameter to accept array
    {
        int id; 
        string[] arrayDocs = docsToDelete;     //no need of deserilization

        foreach (string docId in arrayDocs)
        {
            int.TryParse(docId, out id);
            dal.DeleteDocument(id); // dal = DataAccessLayer is the class which interacts with the database by executing queries (select, delete, update...)
        }

       return Json(id);    //return id back to ajax call...
    }
```

Comment: Am I maybe missing something but VS says that the ActionResult can't be an integer... Cast not working either.

Comment: @Loïc my bad it should be `return Json(id); `

Comment: Ok it makes sense, i'll try