# Checkboxes by class all selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic list of checkboxes all with the same class. I want to disable the submit button until all checkboxes in the class "group1" has been selected.

I also only want to do this, when this class is present on the page.
I was did that part this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="20" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="14" />

if ($(".group1").length > 0) {
 //run below code
 }
```

So I started like this, but am unsure of how to know when, all the checkboxes of that class are selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {

    var checkboxes = $('.group1');
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           //if all chekced, enable submit button
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
       } else {
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
       }

    }
  });
});
```

I have seen this [jQuery Array of all selected checkboxes (by class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099164/jquery-array-of-all-selected-checkboxes-by-class), but as the class can be of any length, I dont know how to check that all are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check like this, total number of checkboxes and total number of checked checkboxes:

```
if ($('.group1').length == $('.group1:checked').length) {
  // all are checked...
  $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
  $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to compare the total number of checkboxes to the number which are checked, like this:

```
var $group = $('.group1');
$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', $group.length != $group.filter(':checked').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = $(".group1:checked").length;
```

Count the checkboxes wich are checked.

Comment: Could you expand this to show how it can help the OP? It seems to be half an answer

Comment: I think that Blawless has 80% of the answer, only a tiny part is missing. You answer looks really smart ...

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to bind an event to checkboxes, to every time they change state to re-run the check to enable or disable the button;

Then you can check if all checkboxes are checked comparing the length of your group vs the length of your group filtered by `:checked` pseudo selector

And to change the state of the submit button, you can use `.prop` method, that accept an attribute and a state of this attribute as a second parameter. So:

```js
$group1 = $(".group1");
$submit = $('[type=submit]');
if ($group1.length > 0) {
    $group1.on('change', checkBoxes)
}

function checkBoxes(){
    var $checked = $group1.filter(':checked'); 
    $submit.prop('disabled', $group1.length != $checked.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="20" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" value="14" />
<input type="submit" disabled>
```