# How to get multiple value of checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I has checkbox the list of media in my webpage

```
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value=<%= item.MediaId %> />> mediaA
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value=<%= item.MediaId %> />> mediaB
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value=<%= item.MediaId %> />> mediaC
```

In my javascript,How can i keep the checkbox value inside the array for example

if user check for mediaA and mediaC in array will be {12,14}

Thanks ^_^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select values of checkbox group with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416752/select-values-of-checkbox-group-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is an option, you can get an array of the values using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```
var vals = $("input[name=c1]:checked").map(function(i, cb) {
  return $(cb).val();
}).get();
alert(vals);
```

`vals` would contain an array of the values of the checked checkboxes, e.g. [12, 14] if A and C were checked in this:

```
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value="12" /> mediaA
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value="13" /> mediaB
<input name="c1"  type="checkbox" value="14" /> mediaC
```