# Get check box values with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have 2 categories of checkboxes.

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo"  value="val1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo"  value="val2" />


  <input type="checkbox" name="bar"  value="val1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar"  value="val2" />
```

When a box is checked I want to run a jQuery function that will assign two variables

```
  var foo = //the values of the checked boxes with the foo name
  var bar = //the values of the checked boxes with the bar name
```

So lets say only the first check box was checked in the foo group where as both were checked in the bar group. The groups values would be as follows

```
 var foo = val1;
 var bar = val1,val2;
```

What is the best way to search through all checkboxes that share the same name/class Look to see if they are checked and if so add their value to a string?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416752/select-values-of-checkbox-group-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
 var foo = $("input:checkbox[name='foo']:checked").map(function(){
                            return this.value;
                        }).get().join(',');

 var bar = $("input:checkbox[name='bar']:checked").map(function(){
                            return this.value;
                        }).get().join(',');
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6PYM/)

Answer (score 2):

Get all checked checkboxes :

```
$(':checkbox').is(':checked').each(function() {
   if ($(this).value) {
     //get values here
   }
});
```

Get all checkboxes :

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
   if ($(this).value) {
     //get values here
   }
});
```

Comment: Does he really want to get all of them ?

Comment: Not really, but I've added the look-for-all in case he wants to use all checkbox values to manipulate further process in his site.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery :checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to the rescue.

Comment: I've looked at that but I can't get a list of values for my life.

Comment: `$('input:checked[name=foo]').val()` will give you the current value checked for "foo"

Answer (score 1):

Give your checkboxes a common class, then:

```
$('.classofcheckbox').each(function() {
   if ($(this).val()) {
     // do stuff...
   }
});
```

Or more directly

```
$('.classofcheckbox:checked').each(function() {
   // do stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkedBoxesToString(name) {
    var checked = [];
    $('[name=' + name + ']:checked').each(function (a, b) {
        checked.push($(b).val());
    });
    return checked.join(",");
}
```