# Array values of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, laravel, checkbox

I just want to value my `check_list[]`, so it will contain array `$file`.

If user clicks checkbox, it will contain all the data in 1 file..

I tried to concatenate but then grouping them was a problem.

I tried hidden values, but got only 1 file values.

```
 @foreach($files as $file)
     <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" ></td>
       <td>{{ $file['file_name'] }}</td>
       <td>{{ $file['file_type'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $file['file_modified'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $file['file_size'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $file['location'] }}</td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Pls. help Im stuck on this problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
var selectedvalues = new Array();
$("input[name='check_list[]']:checked").each(function() {
    selectedvalues.push($(this).val());
});
```

You can see other alternative ways here: [Select values of checkbox group with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416752/select-values-of-checkbox-group-with-jquery)

Comment: i like your idea, but it doesnt work. can i foreach my value in checkbox?

Comment: do you think it is because you dynamically generate the checkboxes?

Comment: so how can i get it then?